# efficent way to sync sql-table with datatable

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datatable

I need to sync a sql-table with data from an DataTable (which is a modified copy of the SQL-table). I'd like to update/delete/insert only the differences, so i need to compare both and find the query-value (in my case ID) and change-type. Is there an efficient way, perhaps via some preset method? I'd like to have as little access as possible.

Comment: using replication that work very quite and efficient.

Comment: could go give an example, or even a tip how to find something about this replication-stuff (what i found was only replication between two sql-dt)? i realy don't know what you mean.

Comment: SQL Server replication is only DB.table-to-DB.table and not appropiate for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create datadapter, set its commands, fill your datatable. Work with your datatable

Then get datatable filled with changes

```
DataTable updateDt = originalDt.GetChanges();

dataAdapter.Update(updateDt);
```

This is the basic logic of working in disconnected mode and updating database.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend a specific practical strategy that you can code yourself, but I recommend that you look at the services provided by the Entity Framework ( SaveChanges, the ObjectContext, adding/removing Entities from the ObjectContext, Include keyword, Navigation and Association properties of related Entities, etc. ) as an estimate of the range and complexity of issues you need to solve.

SQL Server replication framework can also give you some hints ( Merge conflict resolution strategies ).